# MacBook Pro SuperDrive reads CDs/Media DVDs but not Data DVDs

Tags: macbook-pro, dvd, optical-drive

I have a MacBook Pro (Mid-2009) with a SuperDrive that reads CDs, movies DVDs but not data DVDs. Not sure what to do. The data DVDs work well on other MacBook Pros though, so i'm guessing it might be a firmware issue perhaps?

I tried downloading some firmware from support.apple.com but none installed.

This is my SuperDrive: MATSHITA DVD-R UJ-868: Firmware Revision: KB19

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you taken it into to the Genius Bar? it could be some type of hardware issue. Also have you tried resetting the PRAM?